# mySQL prepared statement using "in" clause

Tags: mysql, pdo

Using the PHP PDO library, I'm trying to use a prepared statement, but it's not working. I have this sql:

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE test_table SET zero_or_one_photo = 1 WHERE mls_id = :mls_id AND mls_no in ( :mls_no_list )";
$update_stmt = $dbh->prepare($update_sql);
```

I bind the values:

```
$update_stmt->bindValue( ':mls_id', 'MD-BRIGHT' );
$update_stmt->bindValue( ':mls_no_list', '1234567' );
```

(eventually, I will have many values for the mls_no, but I'm just testing now)

```
$rows = $update_stmt->execute();
print "Execute returns: $rows rows\n";
```

this writes out "Execute returns 1 rows", but the database value is not actually changed. If I change things slightly:

```
 $update_sql = "UPDATE test_table SET zero_or_one_photo = 1 WHERE mls_id = :mls_id AND mls_no in ( '1234567' )";
 $update_stmt = $dbh->prepare($update_sql);
```

I bind just the one value:

```
$update_stmt->bindValue( ':mls_id', 'MD-BRIGHT' );
$rows = $update_stmt->execute();
print "Execute returns: $rows rows\n";
```

Also writes out that 1 row was changed, but this time, the database row actually did change. Is this just the way it is - you can't bind into an "IN ()" clause?

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I normally shy away from ? parameters for clarity, but that should work, I think. Let me try that...

Comment: Here's some [other ideas](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in) if it may be helpful. (similar ideas, different handling)